# `require': cannot load such file -- chartkick (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, sinatra, ubuntu-12.04, chartkick

I have Sinatra and Chartkick working on a Windows development machine. Now I want to move it to a server so others can easily access it.

Here's some relevant details about my server:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]
$ gem -v
1.8.15
$ gem list --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

chartkick (1.2.4)
rack (1.5.2)
rack-protection (1.5.3)
sinatra (1.4.5)
tilt (1.4.1)
$ cat example.rb
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
#require 'chartkick'
get '/' do
  "Hello World"
end
$ ruby example.rb
== Sinatra/1.2.6 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2014-06-06 01:55:43] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-06-06 01:55:43] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2011-10-30) [x86_64-linux]
[2014-06-06 01:55:43] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=9574 port=4567
**<<<redacted>>>** - - [06/Jun/2014 01:55:53] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11 0.0029
**<<<redacted>>>** - - [06/Jun/2014:01:55:53 PDT] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11
- -> /
^C
== Sinatra has ended his set (crowd applauds)
[2014-06-06 01:56:01] INFO  going to shutdown ...
[2014-06-06 01:56:01] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
**<<<removed # from in front of chartkick>>>**
$ ruby example.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- chartkick (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from example.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

Anyone have any clue why the require is failing, or something I can try? I do have a "public" folder with "chartkick.js" in it.

Comment: try the command `ruby -S gem list --local` and ensure that chartkick is listed in the gems actually accessible within the ruby process.

Comment: i get an empty list... ok... but why would sinatra work and more importantly what do i do about it. and thanks!

Comment: I just had a thought - did you perhaps install chartkick as the superuser?

Comment: probably used 'sudo gem install ...', so yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to close the loop: I have multiple versions of ruby installed and I had not changed the link to 1.9.3 before installing the gems. So after I pointed the ruby link to the 1.9.3 executable and the gem link to its 1.9.3 version, I re-installed the gems, and now it works.